# Composition of functions, examples

Tags: functions

Let

\begin{align} 
f(x) &= -1, \\
g(x) &= 3x, \\ 
h(x) &= \begin{cases} 0, & x \text{ even} \\ 1, & x \text{ odd} \end {cases}
\end{align}

now how do you find: $$(f \circ g \circ h)(x),\, g^3,\, \text{and}\, h^{500}?$$

The $h(x)$ is confusing me since I'm not sure how to substitute (for the first one) it in $$ f(g(h(x))).$$

Can someone explain this to me please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The function $f$ is constant, so no matter what the input to it is, the output is $-1$. Thus, you don’t even have to think about what $(g\circ h)(x)$ is: it doesn’t matter.

For $g^3$: what happens to the input when you apply $g$ three times in a row? You multiply it by $3$, then by $3$, again, then ... ?

For $h^{500}$, try looking first at $h^2$, $h^3$, and $h^4$; you should see pretty quickly what’s happening.

Comment: so I assume f(g(h(x)) would be just -1? Since it's constant like you said. For g^3, would it be 9? or 9x? That's what I was wondering..  As for h^500, wouldn't it just be the same function? For example, h^2 would be 0 (since 0^2 is 0) and 1 (since 1^2 is 1)? thanks

Comment: @Rickz0rz: You’re right about the first one. However, $9x$ is $g^2(x)$, not $g^3(x)$: $$g^2(x)=g\big(g(x)\big)=g(3x)=3\cdot3x=9x\;.$$ Can you see what $g^3(x)$ is now?

Comment: Ah I see. It would be $$3^3$$ which is $$27$$. Makes sense. I was confused because the question asked us for $$g^3$$ and not $$g^(3)x$$. What about the last one? Am I correct on that one? Thanks

Comment: @Rickz0rz: I think that you’re still a bit confused about the meaning of $g^3$ here: it’s shorthand for $g\circ g\circ g$, the composition of $3$ copies of the function $g$. Thus, $$g^3(x)=g\big(g\big(g(x)\big)\big)=3g\big(g(x)\big)=3\cdot3g(x)=3\cdot3\cdot3x=27x\;.$$ This means that $g(0)=0$, $g(1)=27$, $g(2)=54$, and so on.

Comment: makes sense thanks

Comment: @Rickz0rz: You’re welcome.

Comment: ah sorry could you tell me if my h(x) is correct? forgot about that one..

Comment: @Rickz0rz: It looks to me as if you may have been confusing exponentiation and composition there. $h^2(x)=h\big(h(x)\big)$; this is $h(0)$ if $x$ is even, and $h(1)$ if $x$ is odd. $0$ is even, so $h(0)=0$, and $1$ is odd, so $h(1)=1$. Thus, $h^2(x)=0$ if $x$ is even, and $h^2(x)=1$ if $x$ is odd. This is exactly the same as $h(x)$, so the function $h^2$, i.e., $h\circ h$, is equal to the function $h$.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense now.. so $$h^{500}$$ would be h(h(h(pretty much 500 times))). That would make it 0, correct (since x is even)?